# What is the purpose of なの in これらの話は本当のことなのか?

Tags: grammar

I heard

> これらの話は本当のことなのか

from this  [video clip about Gozo Shioda sensei](https://youtu.be/LD1enmK_5Ak?t=174).

What is the purpose of なの in これらの話は本当のことなのか?

It seems to be redundant because

> これらの話は本当なのか or これらの話は本当ですか

might be sufficient.

Comment: Are your asking about こと or なの? I think _adjectiveです_ is sometimes more subjective than _adjective+nounです_. The latter is often used to describe something's property rather than one's opinion. I think the なの in this context is used to confirm hearsay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems to be redundant because これらの話は本当*な*のか or これらの話は本当ですか might be sufficient.

Well, if you think the expression これらの話は本当のことなのか has elements that can be dispensed with, *syntactically* you are correct.

My guess is that the scenario incorporated the expression in view of emphasising the subject of the film.